# Using a function to display rendered time inline

Tags: vue.js

I have a list I am iterating through and each item has a unix timestamp.  I have a function to convert the timestamp but I am unsure how to use this inline with Vue.

```
<div 
    v-for="(product,index) in products"
    :key="`product-${index}`"
    class="product">
    <div class="container">
        {{this.formatTime(1555531395)}}
    </div>

</div>

formatTime: function(timestamp) {
    return "testing"
}
```

Comment: formatTime should be a filter: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need the `this`.  Your `v-for` attribute changes the context in child elements to include `product` (and `index`).  So you can do:

```
{{formatTime(product.timestamp)}}
```

Assuming `timestamp` is a property of items in the `products` array.  Also, of course, assuming the `formatTime` function is defined properly in the Vue component's methods: https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html

Comment: The syntax suggests this is vue2  - `key` wasn't introduced until `vue2` it seems

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a way with custom filter:

```js
Vue.filter('formatDate', function(timestamp) {
    var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
    return date.toLocaleDateString("en-US"); // or other format.
})
```

where `yourDateFormatFunction` is of course funciton that you use to format timestamp.

Then, in your template:

```html
<div class="container">
    {{ product.timestamp | formatDate }}
</div>
```